# Python - Using a browser other than Chrome with webbot package

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new to programming and my first task, which should be really simple, is to automate a proccess, where I log in in a website with my credentials, I click on some buttons and that is it. I am using Python 3.6 on windows 10.

I am trying to do it using the webbot module, which so far has come really handy but I have one big problem.

The standard browser for webbot is Google Chrome and thus the site always opens with Chrome. I need to open the site with Internet Explorer.

I have set IE as default browser, but nothing changed, Chrome would still open.

I deleted Chrome, but then when I would run the programm nothing would happen.

I checked the init.py file and the drivers folder of the module and I think that this module can only work with chrome.

Is it possible to use IE or does this mean that this package does not support this browser at all?
Which alternatives would you suggest?
Edit: If I am not mistaken Selenium does not support IE11 on windows 10, so that is not an option, unless I am mistaken.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for another browser other than Chrome (as far as the webbot module is concerned).